# How to get certificate expiration message to all users?

Tags: ios, app-store

whenever any certificate is revoked or expired my client is getting emails. but there are many users created on apple.com for particular account.

Is there any way to specify which users will get those emails ? Actually only client receives this type of emails. But can they give other users such permissions so they also receive each types of emails.

Comment: You really need to work on the question. "whenever any certificate" Does that mean it I revoke a certificate of mine they all will get an email? You need to put effort into the question. An example might also help, what certificate, what email, how is an app id involved, apple.com account, type of email?

Comment: @zaph i think apple users can understand it.

Comment: Oops, I must not be an apple user, I didn't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the people with Agent Role can only get these kind of notification emails.

When your client enrolls in the Apple Developer Program, he automatically becomes the Team Agent for the account. Your client has the option of adding additional developers to the team.There can only be one Team Agent.You guys should be Admin or Member.

Check Out Apple Developer-People tab to see the peoples and their roles.

**Solutions:**

1. Create a new email id for your agent (client) and configure forwarding options for multiple emails (Forward only some emails option)
2. Set up forwarding options in your existing agent email to multiple emails (Forward only some emails option)
3. Create contact groups and provide this as an agent (client) email address/virtual email id on the Apple developer site.

The below links may help you to configure the Forward options

[Automatically forward emails to another account](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957?hl=en)

[Forwarding options](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2707558?hl=en)

Please check [this](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/30970?hl=en) link to create contact groups

Comment: Thanks @Ramshad ,  Yes they have added me as Admin while he is "Admin Legal". But we are not receiving this types of emails while he is.

Comment: Agree @Ramshad this can be done by email. but is there any way by which i can received mail directly? like if client give specific permissions to specific app id and it will receive all the mails.

Comment: There are no options to do it.